# Set initial bootstrap radio button in Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found a plunkr courtesy of @user2789093 in question [AngularJS: Radio buttons do not work with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150988/angularjs-radio-buttons-do-not-work-with-bootstrap-3) and modified it some to reflect my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/sBfSD2?p=info
In angular, I don't think I am supposed to manipulate the DOM, so does anyone have any thoughts on how I could set the intial bootstrap3 radio button to checked without using jquery to check an ID of the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you bind `ng-model` and set the `value` attribute [correctly](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio), the issue doesn't seem to be the value of the resulting radio button selection.  It is only that the bootstrap labels expect an `active` class to be applied if the selection is made.  So you can fix this by adding an `ng-class` to each selection:

```
    <div class="btn-group col-lg-3" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: test.currentVal == 'true'}" ng-click="setTransactionDebit('true')">
            <input type="radio" value="true" ng-model="test.currentVal"></input>
            True
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: test.currentVal == 'false'}" ng-click="setTransactionDebit('false')">
            <input type="radio" value="false" ng-model="test.currentVal"></input>
            False
        </label>
    </div>
```

[Here is a working fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyIvyN?p=preview) of your plunker.

Answer (score 0):

This directive sets the `active` class on a radio input's parent element when the model value equals the input value, and removes the `active` class otherwise.

```
/* Bs radio not setting active class on label because model changes too slowly
 * before $render() in bsRadio inside AngularStrap.  */
myAppDirectives.directive('bsRadioFix',[function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller){
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal){
                elem.parent().toggleClass('active', newVal == attrs.value)
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```