# Angular-Strap Radio Button won't update model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

I want to have a radio-button group as you can see in my code. I use AngularJs, Angular-Strap and Bootstrap.

The problem is, that my variables in the controller won't update when I click another button. The default value is set.
If i remove the labels around the input tags, the update occurs... I don't know if this is a bug, or if I am making something wrong..

I hope I provided any information you need.
Thanks for any help!!

Versions:
AngularJS: 1.2.16
AngularStrap: 2.0.2
Bootstrap :3

HTML:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-additions.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgithub.com/mgcrea/angular-motion/master/dist/angular-motion.min.css">
```

Radio Button:

```
<label class="control-label">Group By:</label>

<div class="btn-group" ng-model="groupBy.value" data-bs-radio-group>
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="all">
    <input name="all" type="radio" class="btn btn-default" value="all">
     All
    </label>

   <label class="btn btn-default" for="room">
     <input name="room" type="radio" class="btn btn-default" value="room">
      Room
   </label>

   <label class="btn btn-default" for="category">
     <input name="category" type="radio" class="btn btn-default" value="category">
      Category
   </label>
</div>
```

Used Libraries:

```
<script src="libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- UI Libs -->
<script src="libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.groupBy = {
    value: 'room'
};
```

Update:

Module Definition:

```
var app = angular.module('deviceApp', ['ngRoute','mgcrea.ngStrap','ngAnimate']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/devices',
        {
            controller: 'DeviceController',
            templateUrl: '/app/partials/devices.html'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/devices' });
});

app.controller('DeviceController', function ($scope, $log, $alert, deviceService) {
  $scope.groupBy = {
    value: 'room'
  };
...

<html data-ng-app="deviceApp">
...
```

Comment: Why did you need `for` attribute of labels? Can you remove them? You code can get work by simply removing `for` attribute of labels.

Comment: Can you show how you define your module?

Comment: The ´for´ label was just an experiment. I thought maybe it would forward the click to the radio-input... It doesn't work without it, too.

Comment: Works without the `for`: http://plnkr.co/edit/SUdgv5rIVdJMLhiHFOiJ?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After I saw this working plnkr I pasted my code into it part by part.
Since it still worked I feeled like I got pranked or something...

So after a loooooong trial and error phase I discovered THE difference....

If I include the jquery.js **after** I include bootstrap.min.js I get the error,  that Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. This resulted to the case, that bootstrap wasn't included correct and everything worked.

At some time in my development I needed Bootstrap.min.js but I noticed, I don't need it anymore. Probably some other file now does that job. So removing the bootstrap.min.js file solved the problem.

Comment: Amazing! It seems that Angular Strap does not need bootstrap.js at all. However I did not find any sign of it in the docs.