# Radio buttons binding is not working when a data-toggle attribute is added in AngularJS + Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, binding, radio-button, buttongroup

I am using AngularJS along with Twitter Bootstrap and I want to make two radio buttons look like normal Bootstrap buttons. I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0nevkwyn/) on jsFiddle and after applying it to my case everything looks fine but it's not working correctly.

I want to bind the radio buttons to a model in Angular. Here's my code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="isMad" ng-model="isMad" ng-value="false" /> No
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="isMad" ng-model="isMad" ng-value="true" /> Yes
    </label>
</div>

<h1>
    I am mad: {{ isMad }}
</h1>
```

And here's the result of clicking on the "No" (radio) button:

[image]

So, the model is not bound at all. When I remove the data-toggle attribute from the button group, everything works correctly but the radio buttons are visualized just on top of the Bootstrap buttons like in this picture:

[image]

What should I do in order to have Bootstrap buttons looking like these in the first picture and working correctly with AngularJS model binding like these in the second one?

Comment: Have you tried setting unique ids for each input element?

Comment: @br3w5 - yup, still not working

Comment: Angular and Bootstrap don't always play well together...https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons provides a directive for implementing radio buttons with bootstrap and angular

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150988/angularjs-radio-buttons-do-not-work-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-change,ng-click dont work with data-toggle="buttons" since v1.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897175/ng-change-ng-click-dont-work-with-data-toggle-buttons-since-v1-3-0)

Comment: This answer should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27897367/1230663

Comment: @br3w5 - you've posted a lot of things, haha. I decided to go for the angular-ui way because I believe it is more straightforward and I'm already using it in my project. Everything works correctly now, so if you give a good example of its usage and post it as an answer, I will choose it as an accepted one so that it could help other people too. :) Thanks for the help, man

Comment: Yes haha quite a few links...I've used angular ui bootstrap successfully for radio buttons so I'll post that as an answer

Comment: Hmm actually i didn't use ui-bootstrap for radio buttons where I thought I did but have it working successfully

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are not the only one that is mad about this issue. Currently I am facing the same problem.

Let me show you my workaround:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{ active : model === 'value1' }">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="model" value="value1" class="hide"> value 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{ active : model === 'value2' }">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="model" value="value2" class="hide"> value 2
    </label>
  </div>
```

The key-point to understand is to remove the `data-toggle="buttons"` which adds additional JavaScript logic that causes the error. And then hide the check-box with the `class="hide"` in the same input which then sets the active state "manually" according to the value of your backing model object.

Comment: just found this issue still exists in Angular 6 - removing data-toggle fixes it

Comment: As @ozz said, this issue was still present in Angular 6 which I resolved by removing `data-toggle="buttons"` and adding `[class.active]="option == 'value'"` to the labels. However I did not need to add `class="hide"` to any of the `<input>`s

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've done it on a previous project with a custom directive for handling scope. Using a custom directive with an isolate scope in this way is optional. It should still work for you using ng-controller - the difference is setting up the radio buttons in the controller not the html then rendering using `ng-repeat`. ([working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgHeocSBlrXxuwQMydLi))

radius.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <legend class="required">Choose a radius</legend>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="radius in vm.radiusValues">
          <div class="check-radio">
            <label for="{{ radius.id }}"> 
              <input type='radio' name="radio" id="{{ radius.id }}" value="{{ radius.value }}"  ng-model="vm.radius">{{ radius.name }} 
            </label>
          </div>  
        </div>

    </fieldset> 

    <p>Selected value is {{ vm.radius }}</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

radius.directive.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('radius', [])
    .directive('radius', radius)
    .controller('RadiusCtrl', RadiusCtrl);

    function radius() {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: 'RadiusCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: 'radius.html'
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function RadiusCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.radius = 500;

        vm.radiusValues = [
            {name: '100m', value: 100, id: 'groupidrad1'},
            {name: '500m', value: 500, id: 'groupidrad2'},
            {name: '1000m', value: 1000, id: 'groupidrad3'},
            {name: '2000m', value: 2000, id: 'groupidrad4'}
        ];
    }
})();
```

The body of index.html

```
<body>
    <radius></radius>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding wise its correct. seems like you have not use proper Angulerjs version. which version u r using ? 
try with 1.3

Comment: i tried with 1.3.8 , same code works perfectly for me.